# RegEx Multiple Matches in Text

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to parse out an email and most of its working except when the record in question comes in with multiple errors.

Here's part of the text

```
Record #1 with LeadRecordID 4 and MTN of (813) 555-1234 has 4 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
   Shipping City cannot be blank
   Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
   Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed. 
Record #2 with LeadRecordID 5 and MTN of (813) 555-4321 has 1 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
```

Here is the RegEx I'm using:

```
Record #(?<RecordNumber>\d*) with LeadRecordID (?<LeadRecordId>\d*) and MTN of .* has (?<NumberOfErrors>\d*) errors:(?:\r\n|)* (?<Error1>.*)
```

**Edit:**
If I do this, I get two matches, with the Error Group only showing one match per group, it should be showing all error lines.
    Record #(?\d*) with LeadRecordID (?\d*) and MTN of .* has (?\d*) errors:(?:\r\n)(?.*)(?:\r\n)

**Edit 2**:
This seems to get me a subgroup, thanks.

```
Record #(?<RecordNumber>\d*) with LeadRecordID (?<LeadRecordId>\d*) and MTN of [^\r\n]* has (?<NumberOfErrors>\d*) errors:(?:\r\n|)*(?<Errors>(?:(?<Error>\s{3}[^\r\n]+)(?:\r\n)*)+)
enter code here
```

Comment: What is the output you want from your regex ? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Each record should be a match, the Errors should come out as an array of matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this pattern and Regex.Matches:

```
@"Record #(?<RecordNumber>\d*) with LeadRecordID (?<LeadRecordId>\d*) and MTN of [^\r\n]* has (?<NumberOfErrors>\d*) errors:(?:\r\n|)*(?<Errors>(?:\s{3}[^\r\n]+(?:\r\n)*)+)"
```

Test code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern =
@"Record #(?<RecordNumber>\d*) with LeadRecordID (?<LeadRecordId>\d*) and MTN of [^\r\n]* has (?<NumberOfErrors>\d*) errors:(?:\r\n|)*(?<Errors>(?:\s{3}[^\r\n]+(?:\r\n)*)+)";

            string message = @"Record #1 with LeadRecordID 4 and MTN of (813) 555-1234 has 4 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
   Shipping City cannot be blank
   Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
   Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed. 
Record #2 with LeadRecordID 5 and MTN of (813) 555-4321 has 1 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank";

            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(message, pattern);

            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("RecordNumber = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["RecordNumber"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("LeadRecordId = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["LeadRecordId"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("NumberOfErrors = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["NumberOfErrors"].Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Errors = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["Errors"].Value);

                MatchCollection errors = Regex.Matches(m.Groups["Errors"].Value, @"\s{3}(?<error>[^\r\n]+)(?:\r\n)*");
                foreach(Match g1 in errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(g1.Groups["error"].Value);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Result:

```
RecordNumber = "1"
LeadRecordId = "4"
NumberOfErrors = "4"
Errors = "   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
   Shipping City cannot be blank
   Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
   Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed.
"
Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
Shipping City cannot be blank
Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed.
------------------------
RecordNumber = "2"
LeadRecordId = "5"
NumberOfErrors = "1"
Errors = "   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank"
Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
------------------------
```

Comment: I'm using Expresso for the testing and that pattern doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Jason Carter, which matching options do you use?

Comment: @Jason Carter, I have added to my solution a bit of changes in RegExp and breaking of full error text into error lines. And I think you should use C# for testing.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do that but looks like I must.  I dropped your code into LINQPad for testing and it works fine.

Comment: I am using expresso and it works fine for me. I think it is related to option setting. Remove multiline option and try again in Expresso.

Comment: Which one works?  The one acoolaum reposted grabs everything fine, I just have to parse the Error collection out seperately, I was hopping to be able to do it in one swoop

Comment: My modification (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390847/regex-multple-matches-in-text/4396477#4396477) grabs Errors collection in one swoop :)

Answer (score 1):

The acoolaum's answer is correct though it uses additional regular expression per match. I changed his code so that it uses only one regular expression. Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string pattern =
@"Record #(?<RecordNumber>\d*) with LeadRecordID (?<LeadRecordId>\d*) and MTN of [^\r\n]* has (?<NumberOfErrors>\d*) errors:\r\n(?:\s{3}(?<Error>[^\r\n]+)(?:\r\n)*)+";

            string message =
@"Record #1 with LeadRecordID 4 and MTN of (813) 555-1234 has 4 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
   Shipping City cannot be blank
   Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
   Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed. 
Record #2 with LeadRecordID 5 and MTN of (813) 555-4321 has 1 errors:
   Shipping Street Address cannot be blank";

    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(message, pattern);

    foreach (Match m in mc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RecordNumber = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["RecordNumber"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("LeadRecordId = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["LeadRecordId"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("NumberOfErrors = \"{0}\"", m.Groups["NumberOfErrors"].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Errors:");

        foreach (Capture capture in m.Groups["Error"].Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", capture.Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Please notice I changed regular expression itself with code to extract matches from Regex (I use [Group.Captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) property to extract multiple matches of group "Error").

Output:

```
RecordNumber = "1"
LeadRecordId = "4"
NumberOfErrors = "4"
Errors:
        Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
        Shipping City cannot be blank
        Shipping Zipcode cannot be blank
        Errors exist in secondary records #2, #3, #4, record not processed.
------------------------
RecordNumber = "2"
LeadRecordId = "5"
NumberOfErrors = "1"
Errors:
        Shipping Street Address cannot be blank
------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell without seeing your code, but you probably need 
`Regex.Matches` as opposed to `Regex.Match`

Answer (score 0):

What do you set as option for matching. Single Line or multiline?

I think you need to change your regex and use multiline option.

Comment: I think he should change pattern only because he didn't use "$" and "^". See my answer.